# Get names of columns in column family without data

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have column family with generated columns and heavy data in it.
Every column has name like PREFIX + TIMESTAMP.
I need to extract timestamp from column name before than I make a decision whether I need to get data from it.
How can I get only names of columns in CF?